# Facing issues in uploading multiple documents Via single API developed in RUBY

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, asihttprequest

I am trying to upload multiple documents (say: images and videos) at the same time with hitting on single API. The API is developed in Ruby ON Rails. I am trying to upload documents in iPhone using ASIHTTP methods. Here is the screenshot of getpostman. On getpostman, It is working fine. Multiple documents are working fine but when I am using same API in xcode then its giving me error.

What I have done till now is, I have used two ways.

1.) Sending multiple documents's data using dictionaries. Here is the code snippet:-

```
[self setRequest:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://onepgr.com/docs/create6_api"]]];
[request setPostValue:@"11" forKey:@"clientname"];
[request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"onepgr_apicall"];
[request setPostValue:pageID forKey:@"page_id"];
//[request setPostValue:@"true" forKey:@"multiple"];
//[request setPostValue:array forKey:@"doc"];
[request setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"passcode"];
[request setPostValue:@"33" forKey:@"clientappkey"];
[request setPostValue:@"22" forKey:@"clientappid"];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:20];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
#endif
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:progressView];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];



//Uncomment For Multiple Upload

for (int i = 0; i<self.chosenImages.count; i++)
{
    UIImage *img = [self.chosenImages objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_File_%d.png",i+1];
    strFileName = str;
    strContentType = @"image/png";

    fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);

    if (i == 0)
        [request setData:fileData withFileName:strFileName andContentType:strContentType forKey:@"doc"];
    else
        [request addData:fileData withFileName:strFileName andContentType:strContentType forKey:@"doc"];
}
```

2.) I have tried sending the data in for loop as well. But nothing worked for me.

Looking forward to have some answers that can help me out.

Thanks,
Nikhil

[image: GetPostMan]

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to check the differences between the 2 requests

My personal bet is that the problem is that you are setting the image data within the loop always to the same key.